# Trouble defining a function using the "codecs" module

Tags: python, python-3.x, encode, codec, rot13

## I am trying to write a simple Rot13 Encoder/Decoder that takes a string and encodes/decodes it using the "codecs" module. I am trying to define a function using: *codecs.encode('rot13_text', 'rot_13')*

I have no problem using using the codecs module outside of a function. When I attempt to define a function using *codecs.encode(rot13_text, 'rot_13')* I receive a NameError

So far I have attempted many variations of the following code:

```
import codecs

def rot13_encoder():
    rot13_text = input("Type the text to be encoded: ")
    codecs.encode(rot13_text, 'rot_13')
    print(rot13_text)
```

## Terminal Output

```
>>> def rot13_encoder():
...     rot13_text = input("Type the text to encode and press enter: ")
...     codecs.encode(rot13_text, 'rot_13')
...     print(rot13_text)
...
>>> rot13_encoder()
Type the text to encode and press enter: HELLO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in rot13_encoder
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'HELLO' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: There's no built-in `rot_13` encoder/decoder. How have you registered your codec to begin with?

Comment: @AKX: There is a built-in `rot_13` codec, at least in some versions of python. (also, hi :)

Comment: OP has tagged their question with `python-3.x` so I assume that's what they're using. (Hi!)

Comment: Your code works for me w/o any errors. I'm using `python 3.7.3`.

Comment: @AKX: It's present in both `python-2.x` and `python-3.x`; I'm not sure when it was introduced to 2.x, but it was apparently missing from 3.x versions before 3.2.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses. The machine i'm currently working on has several Python installs and i'm a bit fatigued. I apologize for the inconvenience. With some subtle changes, it works as I expected it to. I really appreciate you all.

Comment: @AleksiTorhamo Fair enough, so it seems! Though it should be noted that `str.encode('rot_13')` is apparently _not_ supported on Py3; `codecs.encode(..., 'rot_13')` is the only way.

Comment: @AKX: Yeah; IIRC that's because rot-13 is a text-to-text transformation, and at some point it was decided that `str.encode()` and `str.decode()` should only support text-to-bytes and bytes-to-text transformations, respectively, so that their return type is always the same. (Which I think is pretty reasonable)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using python 2.7 or earlier.

```
import codecs

def rot13_encoder(in_string):
    return codecs.encode(in_string, 'rot_13')

in_string = raw_input('Type the text to be encoded: ')
print(rot13_encoder(in_string))
```

in which case you should use `raw_input(...)` instead of `input(...)`

Comment: I like the way you did this. Thank you very much for your correction. I appreciate your quick response. It's working just fine now! Thank you very much